# C Readfile error 87 when trying to read from mailslot

Tags: c, readfile, mailslot

I am trying to set up a mailslot that i can write to and read from.

But when calling ReadFile to i get error 87. I have tried different approaces from MSDN and i still get error 87.

I have removed a lot of error handling in my code in order to shorten it a bit.

This are calls i do from main.

```
hMailslot= mailslotCreate("\\\\.\\mailslot\\myslot"); //works
hMailslot=mailslotConnect("\\\\.\\mailslot\\myslot"); //works
    mailslotWrite(hMailslot,w, lstrlen(w)+1)*sizeof(CHAR); //works
    mailslotRead(hMailslot); //Error 87 invalid parameter
    mailslotClose(hMailslot); //?
```

Here is a shortened version of my code.

```
#define TIME_OUT    MAILSLOT_WAIT_FOREVER 

HANDLE mailslotCreate (char *name) {
    HANDLE H = (HANDLE)CreateMailslot(name,0,TIME_OUT,(LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) NULL);
    return H;
}

HANDLE mailslotConnect (char * name) {

    HANDLE H = CreateFile(name,GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_READ,0,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
            return H;
}

int mailslotWrite(HANDLE mailSlot,void *msg,int msgSize) {

   DWORD cbWritten; 

   WriteFile(mailSlot, msg, msgSize, &cbWritten, (LPOVERLAPPED) NULL); 

   return cbWritten;

}

int mailslotRead (HANDLE mailbox) {

    DWORD cbMessage, cMessage, cbRead; 
    BOOL fResult; 
    LPTSTR Message;

    fResult =GetMailslotInfo(mailbox,(LPDWORD) NULL,&cbMessage,&cMessage,(LPDWORD)NULL);

     if (!fResult) //Works
    { 
        printf("GetMailslotInfo failed with %d.\n", GetLastError()); 
    }

        Message = (LPTSTR) calloc(cbMessage,sizeof(char)); 
        Message[0] = '\0'; 


            fResult = ReadFile((HANDLE)mailbox,(LPVOID)Message,(DWORD)cbMessage,LPDWORD)&cbRead,(LPOVERLAPPED) NULL); 

        if (!fResult)  //Error 87
        { 
            printf("ReadFile failed with %d.\n", GetLastError()); 
            free(Message); 
                 return 0;
        }
        return cbRead;
}

int mailslotClose(HANDLE mailSlot){
    return CloseHandle(mailSlot);
}
```

Comment: Your `mailslotRead` is defined to be accepting 1 argument `int mailslotRead(HANDLE mailbox)` but you're passing it 3 arguments `mailslotRead(hMailslot,w,i)`.

Comment: What is the value of `cMessage` being returned from `GetMailslotInfo`?

Comment: Your casting appalls me. Why don't you want to let the compiler help you?

Comment: Anyway, I believe that you are going to have to pass an overlapped struct.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  He is writing in the style of the MS example code.

Comment: @PeterM The casting is simply appalling. It doesn't matter who writes it.

Comment: @rullof: sorry w and i are removed and not used.

Comment: @PeterM: it contains the number of messages written to the mailslot. In this case it is 1.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have tried using an overlap but i got the same result.

Comment: I cannot comment on that because I cannot see the code. Why don't you start from an example that is known to work?

Comment: My code is a stripped version of the MSDN example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Microsoft, `Error 87` is [ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110148) from ReadFile() or WriteFile()

So something is wrong with those parameters.

Also from MS: [CreateMailSlot()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [CreateFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [ReadFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  definition

I've been looking at [Using Mailslots](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365794%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and trying to compare it to what you have.  About the only difference I can see is that even though they create the file with `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL`, and write to it with `(LPOVERLAPPED) NULL`, they still supply an `OVERLAPPED ov` when reading the file - even though their documentation says that it is not required.

However I don't know enough to know if that is the actual issue

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thats what I'm trying to figure out right now.  I last did pure windows programming in the late 90's

Comment: I do know that it is invalid parameter but since I am not using an overlap it should not occur.

Comment: @PeterM The thing is that even if I add the excact lines used at MSDN for creating the ov with the createEvent I still get the same error.

Comment: @JonathanJuliusSvensson Can you build and run the Microsoft examples as they are?

Comment: @PeterM Combining MSDN [Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365802(v=vs.85).aspx), and [Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365785(v=vs.85).aspx) leaves me with error 87 again.

Comment: @JonathanJuliusSvensson Are you combing the Read/Write into a single program? If so, what happens if they are left as separate programs?

Comment: @PeterM Putting the MSDN examples in separate projects and then running them reader first works. Trying to isolate the differences now. I think it is someting regarding how the handles are created.

Comment: @JonathanJuliusSvensson It could be that the read establishes something that the write doesn't, or it could be that you can't use mailslots to write/read within the same program. Or that you need to create a separate mailslot handle for the read section (with the same name)

Comment: @PeterM The same program should be possible but maybe not the same thread.